# Unexpected shape of "training curves" in NN

Tags: neural-network, training

I'm trying to find the best configuration for my NN (in terms of batch size, learning rate etc) and noticed the following unexpected behavior.

The AUC scores, computed on validation data, as well as the loss (also on validation data) display a "two-step progress". I'm attaching the progress of AUC and loss for 4 of my runs with a variety of learning rates:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, at about 400000 batches (that's more or less after 30 epochs),
it looks like the network gets a "second wind". I think, judging by the loss, that it starts overtraining at around 700000 batches (except in the run with the fastest degrading learning rate).

I've never seen such behavior mentioned before, is this my network escaping some local minimum? Is it normal or something I should be worried about?